# How can you define a variable that will never be matched in Python?

Tags: python

Part of my code relies on a comparison between two items, and it may end up comparing against a variable that doesn't exist. As such I will go through and put in filler variable values for the sets to make sure they both are defined and can be compared.

However, if I add a filler value I don't want it to be possible to be matched to any other value. I'd use None, however it's possible that the other value could also be None. What I'm wondering is if there is a good way to make sure the filler value will not match anything? The already defined values could be anything (as they are user defined).

Also I'm open to suggestions of other ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Any chance you want to share your code? I'm interested to see what you're doing that requires such an unusual solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you could define a custom class to compare against.  For example:

```
class NoValue:
    pass

if someValue is NoValue:
    doSomething()
```

The comparison should always fail, as someValue won't be an instance of NoValue

Comment: Better use the `is` operator, and avoid creating unneeded instances.. Just use plain `NoValue` as you would with `None`.

Comment: For that matter, you could just use `NoValue = object()`.

Answer (score 8):

How about simply:

```
missing = object()
```

and then use `missing` in comparisons (it won't compare equal to any other object, including `None`).

Answer (score 1):

Many times I saw use of `Ellipsis` instead of `None` to mean "the default value" or so..

Anyways, I'm not sure I fully understood your question:

- Which kind of objects are you comparing? `dict`s?
- Can you post some code? I don't see the point of "setting default values to make sure they are defined and can be compared". Why don't you just catch the `KeyError` exception, or use `.get()` ..?

Comment: I could do that, but it seemed unnecessary when all I needed was a negative comparison. Also, I'm comparing strings.

Comment: I don't see how it is "unnecessary".. of course you can use `Ellipsis` or define your own class to use for missing values, but best way would be to catch exception. Again, which comparison are you doing, on which kind of objects? are they dicts of strings?